# Intersection of three samples

Tags: probability, combinatorics

In a city 42% of people read newspaper $A$, 51% people read $B$ and 68% read $C$.

The % of people reading both $B$ and $C$ is 28%

The % of people reading both $A$ and $C$ is 36%

8% people do not read any of the newspapers.

What is the % of people reading all newspapers?

That's my attemp,:

$a+b+c+d+e+f+g=92$ (%
 of people reading newspapers)

$a+b+c+e=42$

$b+c+d+f=51$

$e+c+f+g=68$

$b+c+d+f+e+g=28$

$a+b+c+e+g+f=36$

No of people reading all newspapers is $e$,but how to find it???

Comment: For this type of question,you will often find it useful to use a Venn Diagram.

Answer (score 1):

- $M$ = the percent of people who read $A$
- $N$= the percent of people who read $B$
- $P$= the percent of people who read $C$
- $28 \%$ of people read both $B$ and $C$ = $N \cap P$
- $36 \%$ of people read both $A$ and $C$ = $M \cap P$
- $8 \%$ of people read none of them = $1-(M \cup N \cup P)$

What you are supposed to calculate is $(M \cap N \cap P)$.

Comment: @ Gigili : I still don't get it, by both $union$ is meant rather than $intersection$....or please explain it..

Comment: @HashirOmer: As Rahul suggested, use Venn Diagram to understand it better. See [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509099/venn-diagram-question) which is quite similar to yours.

Answer (score 0):

A Venn-Diagram really is the easiest way to go for these sorts of problems - you can see where overlap is forced to occur.  However, here's the other way.

I don't know to which groups you assigned each of those variables (a through f), but here's the typical notation for this sort of problem.

Imagine you've 100 people.  You've already figured out that we can forget about the 8 that don't read, so we've got 92 to and are dividing them into 3 core groups: group A reads paper A, group B reads paper B, and group C reads paper C.

We know that the union of the groups (all the people who are in at least one of them) is

> **A∪B∪C = 92**

**Quick aside into notation:**

A∪B, or "A union B" is those people who are in group A and/or B.  In this problem, A has 51 people and B has 68.  But, if we just add these numbers together, what happens to those people who are in A and in B?  They get counted twice.  So, we have to subtract them away once.

A∩B, or "A intersection B" is those people who are in both A and B.  The people we just had to subtract away once.

Aside over, it's time to use the inclusion exclusion principle:

> **A∪B = A + B - A∩B**
>
> **A∪B∪c= A +B+C-A∪B-A∪C-B∪C+A∩B∩C**
>
> ...

**A short explanation of the principle:** The ways this works in the first equation is that in adding A and B, we're counting the people who exist in both twice: once in A, and once in B. So, we have to subtract them away once.       In the second equation, when we add A, B,and C we do the same thing and subtract the overlap between A and B, A and C, and B and C. But now, in doing so, the people who are in all three groups have been subtracted one-too-many times, so we have to add them back in once.  You can find out more about [inclusion-exclusion here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

So, trusting this principle, we know our  **A∪B∪C = A + B + C - A∩B - A∩C - B∩C + A∩B∩C**

What we want to know is the value of that last term on the right-hand side - that group of people who are in A, B, and C.  So, rearranging the equation gives us

> **A∩B∩C= A∪B∪C - A - B - C + A∩B + A∩C + B∩C**

Look at the terms now on the right.  All were given except A∩B.

To find A∩B, first you'll need to figure out how many people are in either A or B, but not C.  Then you'll be able to figure out the overlap in A and B